# Why is #if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000) defined?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I found this strange codes in `winnt.h` file in VS2013.

```
#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)  // strange code is here...
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
```

Based on my understanding, when `_MSC_VER` is defined larger than `1000` or less than `1000`, this line `#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000` should equal to `#if 0`. Why `#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000` is this defined in such a strange way?

Comment: probably machine generated code to automatically disable definitions on some builds

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it is *generated* code, with the `0` injected by some stage of the build or packaging process that has discovered the feature is unnecessary on your platform.

Why does it not instead remove the whole `#if` and keep only the `#else` body Because (in general) that would be a lot more difficult and error-prone for a simple tool to do: replacing something that probably looks like `#if <placeholder>` with `#if 0` is easy.

I almost considered trying to figure out precisely what's going on in this specific case, but then I noticed it's WinNT code and decided maintaining whatever remains of my sanity was more important.